# 'Custom' group by in select

Tags: sql, select, group-by, firebird, firebird-3.0

*(edited to minimal reproducible example)*

I needed some help with the following select:

```
Select
   Id_Product, -- product identifier
   Sum(Qt_Sold) Sold_Amount, -- total sum of quantity sold
   Sum(Net_Value) Total_Net_Value, -- total sum of the amount sold
   Case Extract(Month From Date_Sale) || '' || Extract(Year From Date_Sale) -- month and year of product sale
      When Extract(Month From Current_TimeStamp) || '' || Extract(Year From Current_TimeStamp) Then 'Current_Month' -- identifies sales for the current month
      When Extract(Month From DateAdd(Month, -1, Current_TimeStamp)) || '' || Extract(Year From DateAdd(Month, -1, Current_TimeStamp)) Then 'Last_Month' -- identifies last month's sales
      Else 'Past_Months' -- identifies sales from other months
   End Month_Of_Sale
From
   Sale
Group By
   Id_Product,
   Month_Of_Sale -- groups by product identifier and month/year of sale
```

Currently the results are returned as follows:

```
Id_Product | Sold_Amount | Total_Net_Value |   Month_Of_Sale
       '1'            10                20   'Current_Month'
       '1'             5                10      'Last_Month'
       '1'            15                30     'Past_Months'

       '2'            10                30      'Last_Month'
       '2'            20                60     'Past_Months'

       '3'            5                  5     'Past_Months'

       '4'            30               120   'Current_Month'
       '4'            50               200     'Past_Months'

       '5'            5                  5      'Last_Month'
```

The new proposal is: if there were sales in 'Current_Month', group everything here, if not group everything in 'Last_Month', otherwise group everything in 'Past_Months'.

The return from the above example should be:

```
Id_Product | Sold_Amount | Total_Net_Value |   Month_Of_Sale
       '1'            30                60   'Current_Month'

       '2'            30                90      'Last_Month'

       '3'            5                  5     'Past_Months'

       '4'            80               320   'Current_Month'

       '5'            5                  5      'Last_Month'
```

Is there any way to do this grouping?

Answer (score 1):

After some more time looking for a solution, I finally got it. I'll post an answer for future users to have access.

Solution:

```
With Sales As (
   Select
      Id_Product,
      Sum(Qt_Sold) Sold_Amount,
      Sum(Net_Value) Total_Net_Value,
      Case Extract(Month From Date_Sale) || '' || Extract(Year From Date_Sale)
         When Extract(Month From Current_TimeStamp) || '' || Extract(Year From Current_TimeStamp) Then 'MonthA'
         When Extract(Month From DateAdd(Month, -1, Current_TimeStamp)) || '' || Extract(Year From DateAdd(Month, -1, Current_TimeStamp)) Then 'MonthB'
         Else 'MonthC'
      End Month_Of_Sale
   From
      Sale
   Group By
      Id_Product,
      Month_Of_Sale
   Order By
      Id_Product,
      Month_Of_Sale
)
Select
   Id_Product,
   Sum(Sold_Amount) Sold_Amount,
   Sum(Total_Net_Value) Total_Net_Value,
   Min(Month_Of_Sale) Month_Of_Sale
From
   Sales
Group By
   Id_Product
Order By
   Id_Product
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old and only popped up, because someone edited the accepted answer. I'll post my answer still, because the task is slightly simpler than shown in the accepted answer, and maybe a future reader with a similar problem may stumble upon this.

The new request leads to selecting one row per product, so only group by product ID. Then look at the maximum month only. (For this we concatenate month and year with the year first.)

```
select
   id_product,
   sum(qt_sold) sold_amount,
   sum(net_value) total_net_value,
   case max(extract(year from date_sale) || '-' || extract(month from date_sale))
      when extract(year from current_timestamp) || '-' || extract(month from current_timestamp)
        then 'Current_Month'
      when extract(year from dateadd(month, -1, current_timestamp)) || '-' || extract(month from dateadd(month, -1, current_timestamp))
        then 'Last_Month'
      else 'Past_Months'
   end month_of_sale
from sale
group by id_product
order by id_product;
```

Comment: Your solution is simpler, I didn't think to use MAX in CASE.